# Ghostdoc not handling upper case constants with underscores correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ghostdoc

Ghostdoc seems to get massively confused when encountering a `const` that contains underscores. Leaving aside whether constants should be in this format, it seems to me that this could be handled better. I've supplied an example below:

[image]

Aside from refactoring all constants, is there a way to force Ghostdoc to handle these? I didn't see anything that seemed like it could fit the bill in the options.

I'm on version 5.1.16036.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, GhostDoc splits identifiers based on Pascal/Camel naming conventions and pretty much ignores the underscores. We are looking into adding the underscores as delimiters.